# Beaglebone ai-64 board related to device tree configuration

Tags: device-tree

I am trying to configure the device tree for SPI communication with the RFID RC522 module on the beaglebone ai-64 board.

The process of the work to be carried out is as follows.

The information generated when tagging the card of the RFID RC522 module is transmitted to the beaglebone ai-64 board through SPI communication.

I am trying to transmit the received information to a PC using UART communication.

The pin numbers of the beaglebone ai-64 board to be used at this time are as follows.

- reference URL : https://docs.beagleboard.org/latest/boards/beaglebone/ai-64/ch07.html#connector-p9

P_17(header)    SDA(SS) -> GPIO pin: 1 28, register: 0x00011C074, mode 4: SPI6_CS0

P_26(header)    SCK -> GPIO pin: 1 118, register: 0x00011C1DC, mode 0: SPI1_CLK

P_18(header)    MISO    -> GPIO pin: 1 40, register: 0x00011C0A4, mode 4: SPI6_D1

P_21(header)    MOSI    -> GPIO pin: 1 39, register: 0x00011C0A0, mode 4: SPI6_D0

P_1(header) GND

P_10(header)    RST -> RESET

P_6(header) 3.3V    -> V_in

With the above information, we are going to activate SPI and UART interfaces through device tree settings.

Below is the code I wrote.

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-ai-64";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        
        __overlay__ { 
            // overlay-name = "spi-overlay";
            reg = <0x0 0x4>;
            P9_17_pinmux {
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&P9_17_spi_cs0_pin>;
            };

            P9_21_pinmux {
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&P9_21_spi_d0_pin>;
            };

            P9_18_pinmux {
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&P9_18_spi_d1_pin>;
            };

            P9_22_pinmux {
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&P9_26_spi_sclk_pin>;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&spi1>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&spi1_clk_pin>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            channel@1 {
                reg = <1>;
                compatible = "ti,beaglebone-ai-64";
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <&spi6>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&spi6_cs0_pin>, <&spi6_d1_pin>, <&spi6_d0_pin>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            channel@6 {
                reg = <6>;
                compatible = "ti,beaglebone-ai-64";
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

After creating the device tree as above,

```
sudo dtc -O dtb -o runSPI_test.dtbo runSPI_test.dts
```

When I ran the command, the following error occurred.

1. runSPI_test.dtbo: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /fragment@0 has a unit name, but no reg property
2. runSPI_test.dtbo: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /fragment@0/**overlay** has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
3. runSPI_test.dtbo: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /fragment@1 has a unit name, but no reg property
4. runSPI_test.dtbo: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /fragment@2 has a unit name, but no reg property

I wrote all the reg values, but I don't know why this error occurs.

Comment: Are the SPI overlays provided by beagleboard.org:  https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_cape_interface_spec#SPI do not work for you?